# SQL Query returns nothing if string contains '&'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
declare @vchrText varchar(max)
set @vchrText = 'AB&CDC'
 WHILE PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%', @vchrText) > 0 
 Begin
                SET @vchrText = STUFF(@vchrText,

                                      PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9&]%',

                                               @vchrText), 1, '') 
End
print @vchrText
```

While passing @vchrText with '&' in it returns nothing if it is not in then it returns valid result, why.?? What above query does actually..?

Comment: Just get rid of the specialness of the special character with brackets `set @vchrText = 'AB[&]CDC'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your script lies in the pattern of `PATINDEX` used in `STUFF`:

This expression:

```
PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9&]%', @vchrText)
```

contains `&`. Hence, `PATINDEX` returns `0` since `@vchrText` contains `&` character. `STUFF` returns `NULL` when the start index passed to it is `0`. So, you finally receive `NULL` as output when `@vchrText = 'AB&CDC'`.

The pattern of `PATINDEX` used in the `WHILE` predicate *does not* contain `&`. Thus, it correctly detects any *non-alphanumeric* characters contained in `@vchrText`. If `@vchrText` contains *only* alphanumeric characters, then `0` is returned.

**Bottom line**: to fix your script simply fix the pattern of `PATINDEX` used in `STUFF`, use `'%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%'` in place of `'%[^a-zA-Z0-9&]%'`.

Comment: Thanks that works, but how "while" working for each character..?

Comment: @Kailas The first `WHILE` detects the *first* non-alphanumeric character contained in `@vchrText` and `STUFF` strips this character out of `@vchrText`. Hence, the second loop traversal operates on the *next* non-alphanumeric contained in `@vchrText` (because the first non-alphanumeric is not there anymore).